# How to create a continuous palette from 5 colors with specified values for the intermediary cclors?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a palette from green, yellow, orange, red and black.
The minimum value is 0, the maximum value is "infinity".

I would like the following hardcoded values:

0 is  green
20 is yellow
60 is orange
100 is red
max(200, the highest value in the data) is black

can this be specified in colorRampPalette?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this question is tagged with `ggplot2`, I'm guessing you want to use your gradient in a ggplot. `colorRampPalette` gives an evenly spaced vector of colors, and does not associate  them with specific numeric values. It sounds like you are looking for something like `scale_color_gradientn`:

```r
ggplot(data.frame(x = runif(5000, 0, 200), y = runif(5000, 0, 200)), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = (x + y)/2), size = 3) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = c("green", "yellow", "orange", "red", "black"),
                        values = c(0, 20, 60, 100, 200) / 200, limits = c(0, 200),
                        name = "value")
```

[image]

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I needed.  I wasnt aware of scale_color_gradientn().   Thanks for understanding my poorly worded question :)

Comment: to have any values above 200 show up as black:
geom_point(aes(color = pmin( (x+y)/2,200)) , size = 3)